# Does the series $\sum _{n=1} ^{\infty} P\big(\xi_n > \sqrt{2 \ln n + 2 \ln \ln n} \big)$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\{\xi_n\}_{n\ge1}$ be a series of independent normally distributed random variables with $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma = 1$.

> Does the series $\sum _{n=1} ^{\infty} P\big(\xi_n > \sqrt{2 \ln n + 2 \ln \ln n} \big)$ converge?

**Attempt**
Applied [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) and got
$$P\big(\xi_n > \sqrt{2 \ln n + 2 \ln \ln n} \big) \le \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2 \ln n + 2 \ln \ln n} $$
so the series in question converges if 
$$\sum _{n=1} ^{\infty} \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2 \ln n + 2 \ln \ln n}$$
does. But then I got stuck trying to prove this latter statement.

Comment: The series $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\ln n + \ln \ln n}$ diverges because $\frac{1}{\ln n + \ln \ln n}\geq\frac{1}{n}$ for large $n$.

Comment: You could try using [the asymptotic expansion of the complementary error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Asymptotic_expansion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: The series you mention, as pointed out in a comment, diverges. But you probably gave up a lot using Chebyshev. You can get a better estimate using L'Hopital on

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2/2}\,dt}{e^{-x^2/2}/(2x)}.$$