# Does the series $\sum\limits_{n\geq3}P\{\xi_n>\sqrt{2\ln n+2\ln\ln n}\}$ converges?

Tags: calculus, probability, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, normal-distribution

Let $\xi_n$ be a sequence of the random variables with standard normal distribution.
Does the following series
$$\sum\limits_{n\geq3}P\{\xi_n>\sqrt{2\ln n+2\ln\ln n}\}$$
converges?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but here's a hint for how to get an upper bound on that tail: If $A>0$ then $\int_A^\infty e^{-t^2/2}\le A^{-1}\int_A^\infty te^{-t^2/2}$.

Comment: this problem is similar to the iterated logarithm, but i don't understand how can we use it...

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2823694/does-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-p-big-xi-n-sqrt2-ln-n-2-ln-ln-n/2824040#2824040

Comment: Duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2823694/does-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-p-big-xi-n-sqrt2-ln-n-2-ln-ln-n/2824040#2824040

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $A>0$ then $$\int_A^\infty e^{-t^2/2}\le A^{-1}\int_A^\infty te^{-t^2/2}=A^{-1}e^{-A^2/2}.$$Hence $$P\{\xi_n>\sqrt{2\ln n+2\ln\ln n}\}
\le\frac c{\sqrt{\ln n}}e^{-(\ln n+\ln\ln n)}=\frac c{n(\ln n)^{3/2}},$$so the sum converges.

**Bonus:** At first blush that upper bound on the integral look fairly rough. But it's actually not far from the truth, since the exponential dies so fast. If $A>1$ then $(A+1/A)^2<A^2+4$, so $$\int_A^\infty e^{-t^2/2}\ge\int_A^{A+1/A}e^{-t^2/2}\ge A^{-1}e^{-(A+1/A)^2/2}\ge\frac 1{e^2A}e^{-A^2/2}.$$

Which means we can pin this one down:

**Exercise:** $\sum P\{\xi_n>\sqrt{2\ln n+\alpha\ln\ln n}\}$ converges for $\alpha>1$ and diverges for $\alpha\le1$.

Comment: You make it seem so easy.

Comment: @saulspatz Nah, it just happens that a little while ago I needed to know what we could say about the growth of $\xi_n$, so I already knew how to do this one...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, Thank you very much!